# Kali linux not detecting bluetooth adapter

Tags: linux, bluetooth, kali-linux, sony-vaio

I have installed kali linux and bluetooth was running fine until I updated it. The bluetooth service showing active but bluetooth manager is not opening.

```
$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: disab>
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-11-27 22:16:20 IST; 16min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 4365 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 6633)
     Memory: 812.0K
        CPU: 74ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─4365 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Nov 27 22:16:20 Sony-Vaio systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Nov 27 22:16:20 Sony-Vaio bluetoothd[4365]: Bluetooth daemon 5.65
Nov 27 22:16:20 Sony-Vaio systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Nov 27 22:16:20 Sony-Vaio bluetoothd[4365]: Starting SDP server
Nov 27 22:16:20 Sony-Vaio bluetoothd[4365]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 in>
```

running bluetoothctl it shows "no default controller availabel".

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl        
[sudo] password for bhoumik: 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]#
```

I have restarted bluetooth service, but it isn`t worked.

how do I start using bluetooth again?

Comment: [If you need to ask, then Kali Linux is not the right distribution for you.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/454022)